# Newbie's question for Erlang dict

Tags: erlang

I'm reading *Programming Erlang by Joe Armstrong(Pragmatic Bookshelf)*. In name_server.erl source code on Chapter 16, Where's **Dict** variable from? Calling dict:new() generates Dict automatically? And, reference says that dict:new() creates dictionary. Don't I need to store it as a variable like **Dict = dict:new()**?

```
-module(name_server).
-export([init/0, add/2, whereis/1, handle/2]).
-import(server1, [rpc/2]).

add(Name, Place)  ->
  rpc(name_server, {add, Name, Place}).

whereis(Name) ->
  rpc(name_server, {whereis, Name}).

init()  ->
  dict:new().

handle({add, Name, Place}, Dict)  ->
  {ok, dict:store(Name, Place, Dict)};
handle({whereis, Name}, Dict) ->
  {dict:find(Name, Dict), Dict}.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is part of a two file example. The other file (immediately before it in the book) is `server.erl`. It contains a `loop` function that calls the `handle` function in `name_server.erl` (or whatever module you pass to it):

The line is:

```
{Response, State1} = Mod:handle(Request, State),
```

where `Mod` is the module passed to `start` earlier. And `State` is initialised earlier as `Mod:init()` in the start function.

So `State` is initialised to `name_server:init()` which in your file returns `dict:new()`. However, as `loop` is called recursively `State` will take the next value of `State1`.

So when `handle` is called, `Dict` is set to the current value of `State`.